# VB.Net Is there a way to for an interface to inherit from another interface?

Tags: .net, vb.net, inheritance, interface

I have 2 interfaces, IAccount and IEmailAccount.  IEmailAccount contains all of the same properties and methods as IAccount, plus a few extensions related to email.  Is there a way to do something similar to class inheritance with Interfaces?  I tried removing all of the common properties/methods shared between the 2 from IEmailAccount, but if I have a List of IAccounts, I want to be able to include IEmailAccounts in that list...

```
Public Interface IAccount
    Property Username As String
    Property Password As String
    Property LoginCookie As Net.CookieContainer
    Property CreationDate As Date
    Property LastLoginDate As Date
    Property EmailAccount As IEmailAccount
    Property Proxy As HelperLib.Proxy
    Sub Login()
    Sub Create()
End Interface

Public Interface IEmailAccount
    Property Username As String
    Property Password As String
    Property LoginCookie As Net.CookieContainer
    Property CreationDate As Date
    Property LastLoginDate As Date
    Property EmailAccount As IEmailAccount
    Property Proxy As HelperLib.Proxy
    Property Emails As List(Of Email)

    Sub Login()
    Sub Create()
    Sub SendMail(recipient As String, title As String, body As String)
    Function GetEmails() As List(Of Email)
End Interface

Public MustInherit Class EmailAccountBase
    Implements IEmailAccount
    Implements IAccount

    Public Property Emails As List(Of Email) Implements IEmailAccount.Emails
    Public Property Username As String Implements IEmailAccount.Username, IAccount.Username
    Public Property Password As String Implements IEmailAccount.Password, IAccount.Password
    Public Property LoginCookie As CookieContainer Implements IEmailAccount.LoginCookie, IAccount.LoginCookie
    Public Property CreationDate As Date Implements IEmailAccount.CreationDate, IAccount.CreationDate
    Public Property LastLoginDate As Date Implements IEmailAccount.LastLoginDate, IAccount.LastLoginDate
    Public Property EmailAccount As IEmailAccount Implements IEmailAccount.EmailAccount, IAccount.EmailAccount
    Public Property Proxy As Proxy Implements IEmailAccount.Proxy, IAccount.Proxy

    Public MustOverride Sub Login() Implements IEmailAccount.Login, IAccount.Login
    Public MustOverride Sub Create() Implements IEmailAccount.Create, IAccount.Create
    Public MustOverride Sub SendMail(recipient As String, title As String, body As String) Implements IEmailAccount.SendMail
    Public MustOverride Function GetEmails() As List(Of Email) Implements IEmailAccount.GetEmails

    Public Sub New(username As String, password As String)
        Me.Username = username
        Me.Password = password
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: An interface inherits another interface in EXACTLY the same way as a class inherits another class.  You declare an interface and then add `Inherits IBase` in the definition. That's exactly how `IList` inherits `ICollection` inherits `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Ok, I was trying to use Implements IBase instead...not sure what I was thinking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's simple:

```
Public Interface IAccount
    Property Username As String
    Property Password As String
    Property LoginCookie As Net.CookieContainer
    Property CreationDate As Date
    Property LastLoginDate As Date
    Property EmailAccount As IEmailAccount
    Property Proxy As HelperLib.Proxy
    Sub Login()
    Sub Create()
End Interface

Public Interface IEmailAccount
    Inherits IAccount
    Property Emails As List(Of Email)

    Sub SendMail(recipient As String, title As String, body As String)
    Function GetEmails() As List(Of Email)
End Interface
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I swear I had tried this the other day and the IDE said 'nope'...hence me asking this question in the first place.  Derp...I had been trying to use Implements IBase instead :(